# Parse literal string as if enclosed by double quotes

Tags: vimscript

Let's say I have string like this:

```
let a = 'iHello<cr>World'
```

Now I can use it for a remap:

```
execute 'nnoremap a '.a
```

But in order to use it with `normal!`, I would have to convert `<cr>` to a literal newline.
I know I can do this:

```
let b = escape(a, '<')
```

Now `b` is 'iHello\World'. But how can I parse it to become 'iHello\nWorld' (where \n is a literal linefeed character)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `<cr>`, use `^M` in your string:

```
let a = 'iHello^MWorld'
```

You can insert this with `<C-v>`+`<CR>`, this is a graphical representation of a newline in vim.

It will work in those cases:

```
:execute "normal ".a
:execute "normal! ".a
:execute "nnoremap a ".a     (then press a in normal mode)
```

Now if your want to make it work in the following case:

```
:execute "nnoremap a :normal! ".a     (then press a in normal mode)
```

You need to use the following (c.f. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37617159/2558252)):

```
let a = 'iHello<C-v><CR>World<CR>'
```

Comment: You got to it before me. :P

Comment: Well, it won't work with `:normal` since the `^M` will execute it. You need `^V^M` in the string to use it with `:normal`.

Comment: How so? I made it work... Can you add some details please?

Comment: `:let a = 'iHello^MWorld' | exe 'nno a :normal! ' . a`

Comment: Needs to be: `:let a = 'iHello^V^MWorld^M' | exe 'nno a :normal! ' . a`

Comment: Working here without the extra `^V` ...

Comment: [Same Q. on main](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37614371/get-raw-string-value/37617159#37617159)

Comment: @FizzyTea: my bad, you're right, I didn't see the second example, let me update that. Thanks for the detail :)

Comment: I was really confused about `^M`, but then I noticed, that `^M` is actually the graphical representation of a carriage return in vim, not necessarily a newline, maybe you should edit that.